# What is the most efficient way of running futures in scala?

Tags: scala, concurrency, akka

Currently we use :

```
val simpleOps: ExecutionContext = Akka.system(app).dispatchers.lookup("akka.actor.simple-ops")
```

Then we implicitely import this when we create and compose our futures. Other than that we currently don't use Akka.

There are easier ways to get ExecutionContext, but I am not sure that it is going to run over Java Fork/Join Pool, which is a bit more performant than regular java ExecutorService.

Is Akka the only way to get FJP powered ExecutionContext? 
Are there any other ways to get ExecutionContext that are as performant that Akka FJP MessageDispatcher?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scala futures already use ForkJoinPool under the hood (specifically, they use a scala specific fork of java's ForkJoinPool).

See https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.1/src/library/scala/concurrent/impl/ExecutionContextImpl.scala#L1

In particular, notice that `DefaultThreadFactory` extends `ForkJoinPool.ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory`:

```
class DefaultThreadFactory(daemonic: Boolean) extends ThreadFactory with ForkJoinPool.ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory
```

Comment: Cool, thank you for the reponse. Do you still see any point of using Akka dispatchers for this?

Comment: If you just use Futures, then probably not